# Wix can't add Custom Action to project

Tags: c#, wix

Wix 3.9, Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
[image: Disappear files]

I want to add a Custom Action to my Setup Project. But the list only files WIX. I tried to reinstall Wix. I tried to install version 3.9 or 3.10. No results.
As well, the project fails to connect Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll and Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package.dll
  What I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a CustomAction directly to a WiX installer project. You need to create a CustomAction project to hold the action and then reference it within your Installer project.

Comment: Is there a trick to adding said reference? Right clicking References/Going to Projects tab/Highlighting my custom action project/Hitting add/Hitting OK doesn't seem to have any effect on "Unresolved reference to symbol 'Binary:xyz' in section 'Fragment:'" build failures.

Comment: How are you referencing the dll? Are you referencing the .net output or the CA output? It should look something like <Binary Id="CustomAction.dll"            SourceFile="$(var.WixCustomActions.TargetDir)\$(var.WixCustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />

Comment: I wasn't adding anything to my .wxs, thinking that Visual Studio would automagically handle this for me per right clicking References etc. as described above. I later (manually) added a <Binary/> tag, which fixed it.